# How to use retrofit cache when server is shut down and there is no response?

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit to getting data from the server, I enabled the caching system and it's working fine but only when the user is offline.
I want to use retrofit cache when the server did not respond.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

I'm using these Interceptors and I added them to my client.

```
static Interceptor onlineInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 60 seconds even if there is internet connection
        return response.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .build();
    }
};

static Interceptor offlineInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (!isInternetAvailable()) {
            int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // offline cache available for 30 days
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                    .removeHeader("Pragma")
                    .build();
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
};

public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Take a look https://medium.com/mindorks/caching-with-retrofit-store-responses-offline-71439ed32fda

Comment: Thank you, but i want to use retrofit cache when server is shut down.